# 1264 Out of range value adjusted for column com campo decimal

Tags: mysql, decimal

Tenho uma tabela hotel em meu banco de dados com uma coluna `estrelas(decimal(1,1))` que recebe a nota do hotel (de 0,0 a 5,0), porem sempre que eu tento inserir ou alterar um campo e colocar um valor maior que 0,9 ele nao grava dando este alerta:

> Warning: #1264 Out of range value adjusted for column 'estrelas' at row 1

e o valor volta para 0,9.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser isso?
Já deletei a tabela e recriei com esse codigo sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_db.Hotel (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    endereco VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    estrelas DECIMAL(1,1);
)
```

mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no tipo de dado. Tenta mudar pra `decimal(3,2)`. De acordo com a documentação, o primeiro parâmetro é o número máximo de dígitos, enquanto o segundo é a quantidade de números do lado direito do ponto decimal.

Comment: Entao @user42020 coloquei o campo como decimal(2,1) e funcionou.

Comment: Quanto ao primeiro numero ser a quantidade de digitos, eu ja sabia, por isso tinha colocado decimal(1,1) pois eu ia inserir valores como 0.5, 2.5, 3.5 entendeu?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Que bom que resolveu. :)